# PostgreSQL in Docker - pg_hba.conf to allow access from host to container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to run PostgreSQL inside a Docker container. I am building my own Docker image, as I want to include PostgreSQL extensions. I should edit the `pg_hba.conf` configuration file to:

1. allow access originating from other containers
2. allow access originating from the host

The first is quite simple: I can add a rule for `172.17.0.0/16` if I am not mistaken.

But how can I approach the second? What does the IP (or range) looks like when the host connects to psql in a container?

Remark: I am starting the container via `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432`, so in theory I could just allow `all` in `pg_hba.conf` because the port forwarding is only bound to `127.0.0.1`. But I prefer this extra level of security in `pg_hba.conf` for the situation when I (probably by mistake) run the container via `docker run -p 5432:5432`. I hope this makes sense.

**update**

Actually, setting range `172.17.0.0/16` does not seem to be correct. For example, my container had IP `172.18.0.2` in my test. There does not seem to be a consensus on the default range or how to configure that range, according to my investigations so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check your docker0 bridge interface in your case it might be 172.18.0.0/16

make changes in postgresql.conf path will be same as pg_hba.conf.

listenaddress to "*"

Then in pg_hba.conf add rule as

host all  all 172.18.0.0/16 md5.

run the docker with hostip : docker run -p :5432:5432
in this way other containser on same docker n/w can connect aswell as from host,but not from other hosts.

Comment: Can you explain why you set `172.18.0.0/32` in pg_hba.conf? Why not `172.18.0.0/16`?

Comment: sorry its typo correct value is 172.18.0.0/16  /32 give single container ip.