# Add custom pg_hba.conf in postgres docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I want to expose `5432` port to be accessible externally, but before doing that I want to limit it to only specific IPs, so I want to do that via `pg_hba.conf`

If I use docker default settings, communication between containers, works fine (by specified networks).

But if I specify `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host    all             all             all                     md5
```

And try to use this `pg_hba.conf` file (which is actually straight copy from container itself):

`psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution` (where `db` is postgres db service in docker-compose.yml).

My compose has this for postgres:

```yaml
  other: # other service that connects to postgres using psycopg2
    networks:
      - backend
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql.conf"]
    ports:
      - 5432:5432  # for external communications
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - path/to/cfg:/etc/postgresql.conf
      - path/to/hba:/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
  networks:
    - backend

  networks:
    backend:
```

And then in `postgresql.conf` I have edited this line:

`hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf'`

Also config has this set: `listen_addresses = '*'`

Inspecting docker network:

```
docker network inspect bridge 
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "fe4fe8b8eb4e0c06d43428eadd2bb3f44a2ac581fe55618b4c70c5c28c107b8d",
        "Created": "2022-11-26T09:34:03.461094956+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

P.S. I checked

[PostgreSQL in Docker - pg_hba.conf to allow access from host to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423173/postgresql-in-docker-pg-hba-conf-to-allow-access-from-host-to-container)

And [How can I allow connections by specifying docker-compose host names in postgres's pg_hba.conf file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173448/how-can-i-allow-connections-by-specifying-docker-compose-host-names-in-postgres)

But none seem to make any difference.

UPDATE:

I retried again, using same thing. Just specifying `pg_hba.conf` and now I don't get that error. Not sure how it was solved. But `pg_hba.conf` is picked up just fine and I can limit access with it.

Comment: Did you try `depends_on: - db` for the `other` service? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on

Comment: Yes its there. But I don't think its related. Its only relevant when service is being loaded, so it would wait for dependency. But even when service is loaded fully, you can't connect to it, if I add `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Show us var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf output

Comment: @RichardRublev it does not have much. The only difference from default conf is just that I have some custom tunings (for postgres to better use machine resources) and that I specify `hba_file` to use custom one.

Comment: I created this gist that attempts to replicate the issue https://gist.github.com/Spalaiokostas/446873a9c6a1e535b226201f3ce47f1d but everything works as expected. Is there any other configuration that we are missing?

Comment: Are you using the `network_mode: bridge` configuration on any of the service definitions in the docker compose file?

Comment: @spyrospal I only use named networks without any options, like
```networks:
      backend:
      frontend:
```
And thats it.

Comment: Does simple `ping` works from any other container to the `db` one?

Answer (score 2):

Try to keep both config files on the default place (in /var/lib/postgresql/data) and revert the change for hba_file location. Make sure the files have the same permission and ownership as in container: 600 postgres:postgres (999:999)

**EDIT:**

Just looked in the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres). They start pg with custom config like this:

```
$ docker run -d --name some-postgres -v "$PWD/my-postgres.conf":/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres -c 'config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf'
```

where postgres before "-c" is the image name. I think you should redirect "-c" part to entrypoint.

**EDIT2:**

You're right, according to [the entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/13/bullseye/docker-entrypoint.sh) this call with "postgres" as a parameter also works.

Comment: No, its a bad idea to put custom config files in data dir, because this one is used by another volume to have databases persist between containers recreation (`db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`). For this reason `postgresql.conf` is also moved outside and I use command to specify path to it.

Comment: I see, there is not much what can go wrong here. I think you start pg container wrong, check my updated answer.

Comment: I dont think I start it wrong. I basically start it the same way. Its just I use docker compose to run it instead.

Comment: In `command: ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql.conf"]` postgres is a part of command, but there is no command `postgres` - it's the image name. "-c" part goes to its entrypoint.

Comment: Just use `command: ["-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql.conf"]`

Comment: Postgres starts either way. But I agree, its weird to use `postgres`. I picked it up from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228881/1455384 to me it looked weird that `postgres` is used as "command", but it worked, so I left it..:)

Comment: So you omitted creating a custom settings file on different location as I suggested and it worked? :)

Comment: No. Its working either way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` as an environment variable on the docker-compose.yml for the the `db` container, otherwise the postgres will failed with:

```
tmp-db-1     | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
tmp-db-1     |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
tmp-db-1     |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
tmp-db-1     |
tmp-db-1     |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
tmp-db-1     |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
tmp-db-1     |
tmp-db-1     |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
tmp-db-1     |        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

If it still fails could you share the logs of the db container?

Comment: I can use postgres and connect to it just fine (i pass needed credentials) if I dont use `pg_hba.conf`. I pass POSTGRES_PASSWORD (in prod I pass POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE) and it connects.